# Modeling Pipeline Budget

Tags: recommender-system, time-series

I have been tasked with creating a pipeline chart with the live data and the budgeted numbers.

I know what probability of each phase of reaching the next.  The problem is I have no Idea what to do about the pipeline budgeting with regards to time.  For instance what period of time should I have closed sales in the chart.

I have honestly been working on trying to figure it out.  Each successive revision gets me farther from the answer.

Comment: I'm sure this is tagged incorrectly and not enough info.  But i dont know what i dont know at this point

Comment: Can you give more detail on the data? it's not clear what pipeline means here, what type of data is in question, or what the budget concern is.